# JavaScript Can't not find variable

Tags: javascript, html

When you hover your mouse over the carousel-container
I want a modal to appear when a white div appears and is clicked.
When I hover the mouse, onmouseover, onmouseout, and onmouseover work and the error "can't find variable HandleCarouselContainerHover" occurs. What is the cause?

here is my JS code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const topbanners = document.querySelectorAll('.banner');
    let topBannerIndex = 0;

    // carousel-container
    const carouselContainers = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-container');

    // carousel-container card mouseHover
    function handleCarouselContainerHover(event, action) {
        try {
            const container = event.currentTarget;
            const projectTitle = container.querySelector(".project-title");
            const overlay = container.querySelector('.overlay');

            if (action === 'show') {
                overlay.style.display = 'flex';
                projectTitle.style.opacity = '1';
            } else if (action === 'hide') {
                overlay.style.display = 'none';
                projectTitle.style.opacity = '0';
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error in handleCarouselContainerHover:', error);
        }
    }

    carouselContainers.forEach((carouselContainer, index) => {
        const carousel = carouselContainer.querySelector('.carousel');
        const totalSlides = carousel.querySelectorAll('.card').length;
        const slideWidth = carousel.querySelector('.card').offsetWidth;
        let currentIndex = 0;

        function moveToSlide(index) {
            if (index < 0) {
                index = totalSlides - 1;
            } else if (index >= totalSlides) {
                index = 0;
            }

            currentIndex = index;
            const translateValue = -index * slideWidth;
            carousel.style.transform = `translateX(${translateValue}px)`;
        }

        //carousel card 조작
        function handleCarouselSlide(direction) {
            if (direction === 'next') {
                currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % (totalSlides - 2)
            } else if (direction === 'prev') {
                currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + (totalSlides - 2)) % (totalSlides - 2);
            }
            if (currentIndex === totalSlides - 1) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    moveToSlide(0);
                });
            } else {
                moveToSlide(currentIndex);
            }
        }

        const prevButton = carouselContainer.querySelector('.control-button#prev');
        const nextButton = carouselContainer.querySelector('.control-button#next');

        prevButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            handleCarouselSlide('prev');
        });

        nextButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            handleCarouselSlide('next');
        });

        //carousel card Overlay
        const overlay = carouselContainer.querySelector('.overlay');

        // mouseover, mouseout 이벤트 리스너
        // mouseover, mouseout 이벤트 리스너
        carouselContainer.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
            handleCarouselContainerHover(event, 'show');
        });
        carouselContainer.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {
            handleCarouselContainerHover(event, 'hide');
        });
        carouselContainer.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            if (event.target.classList.contains('carousel-container')) {
                openModal.call(carouselContainer);
            }
        });

        carouselContainer.dataset.index = (index + 1).toString();
    });

    //carousel card modal 조작
    function openModal() {
        try {
            var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
            var modalTitle = modal.querySelector("h3");
            var modalContent = modal.querySelector("p");
        
            if (carouselContainer.dataset.index === '1') {
                modalTitle.innerText = "프로젝트 1 모달";
                modalContent.innerText = "프로젝트 1 설명";
            } else if (carouselContainer.dataset.index === '2') {
                modalTitle.innerText = "프로젝트 2 모달";
                modalContent.innerText = "프로젝트 2 설명";
            }
        
            modal.style.display = "block";
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error in openModal:', error);
        }
    }
});
```

1. Check if the function definition is correct
2. Check function name or script loading order
3. Make sure the function definition and call match
4. Check that the scope of the function is valid where it is called

Comment: @James Why do you say that? The scope of a variable in a function includes functions that are nested inside it.

Comment: Please post the exact error message. You wrote `Handle` with an uppercase `H`, but that doesn't appear anywhere in the code.

Comment: I was under the impression that the carousel container.forEach occurred outside of the domcontentloaded handler where it clearly doesn’t.  Sigh.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry. Here is the error message
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: handleCarouselContainerHover
'''
<div class="carousel-container" id="carouselContentContainer1" onmouseover="handleCarouselContainerHover(this, 'show')" onmouseout="handleCarouselContainerHover(this, 'hide')" onclick="openModal(this)">
'''
This is error message line in html